# Problem creating a copy of \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, framed, pandoc, adjustbox

I've edited this to more clearly state my question.  I've had some wonderful suggestions, but they are all pointing at something that's working just fine.

I am trying to define a macro `\embedimage` that is effectively a copy of the original `\includegraphics` macro.  I am doing so because I *must* `\renewcommand` `\includegraphics` to support something that's coming out of Pandoc.  Regardless of how I approach this, I cannot seem to get the new macro to embed an image without a frame.

### Original details follow:

First, the way I'm using LaTeX is a bit nonstandard and out of my control.  I am trying to influence an environment that has long generated books from Powerpoint files.  I've managed to get them to *try* Markdown, but the organization is definitely not ready for full on TeX.

That said, I'm including the following in my preamble:

```
---
geometry: "left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm"
output: pdf_document
documentclass: extarticle
fontsize: 12pt
monofont: "Courier New"
toc: true
include-before: |
    ![](./media/Slide1.png){ width=100% }
    \pagebreak
header-includes: |
    \iffalse
    The following packages and configurations accomplish the following:
        % wrapfig is used to allow inset images with runaround
        % Support building indices
        % Set title to nothing so we can override
        % Reset footnote numbering on each page
        % Support TTF and other fonts and arbitrary font sizes
        % Support inline LaTeX style mathematics notation
        % Reconfigure slide images to include borders
    \fi
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[intoc, title=]
    \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics
    \renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphicsbak[frame,#1]{#2}}
    \newcommand{\embedimage}[1][]{\includegraphicsbak[frame=0pt, #1]}
---
```

Notice that I am redefining `\includegraphics` to frame the image since the org is accustomed to having slides with borders at the start of every page.  What I really ought to do is define a `\slide` macro that does this, but then they lose the preview of the slide in the Markdown preview tool that they are using.  Pandoc, when converting embedded images, uses `\includegraphics` and I have not found a way to customize the conversion from the markdown to that macro.

This brings me to my actual problem.  I have other embedded images on pages elsewhere in the document.  I am struggling to find a way to prevent the frame from `\adjustbox` from appearing on these images as well.  My latest attempt can be seen in the preamble above... and it does not work.

I have also tried including the following prior to the redefinition in the `\renewcommand` or even loading `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`:

```
\let\embedimage\includegraphics
```

This does not work either.

My understanding was that using `\let\embedimage\includegraphics` prior to the redefinition would effectively create an evaluated copy of `\includegraphics` in `\embedimage`, but it still carries the frame.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try swapping the arguments: `\renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphicsbak[#1,frame]{#2}}`

Comment: Mmm... The thing you are pointing at is working just fine.  This is redefining \includegraphics so that the default works properly from Pandoc

Comment: Does `\let\embedimage=\includegraphicsbak` work?

Comment: Nope.  Still have a frame. :(

Answer (score 2):

The order in which you supply the optional arguments for `\includegraphics` (when loading [`\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)) is important, since the application of elements are performed in that order. So, with

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphicsbak[frame,#1]{#2}}
```

you insert a `frame` (of default thickness `\fboxrule` which is `1pt`) around the image. If that image is then reduced in size, the `frame` is also reduced with it. For large images this may make the `frame` completely invisible. To see why this is the case, consider the following minimal (LaTeX) example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{20pt}% Adjust thickness of default frame rule

\includegraphics[frame,width=5cm]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=5cm,frame]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

In both cases the `frame` is now visible, but it's thinner in the first example than the second, because `frame` is specified *before* the scaling (`width=5cm`, which results in a reduction of the image size). In the second example the `frame` is inserted *after* the scaling, resulting in the expected thick `20pt` border.

Since order of optional argument are important, place the `frame` last:

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics
\renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[1][]{\includegraphicsbak[#1,frame]}
\newcommand{\embedimage}[1][]{\includegraphicsbak[#1]}
```

Setting `frame=0pt` is not really needed either, so I've removed it. There's also no official need for grabbing the second (mandatory) argument in either the renewed `\includegraphics` or `\embedimage` (as you've already done).

Comment: THanks for this, but I wonder if I've misstated my question.  The slide and slide frame works just fine.  I'm trying to define a separate macro \embedimage that *does not have a frame* even though \includegraphics has been redefined.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: Sure. Then use `\newcommand{\embedimage}[1][]{\includegraphics[frame=0pt,#1]}`, right?

Comment: I have actually tried that and still seem to end up with a frame!  Let me try it again.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: It will end up with a frame if you use my original redefinition of `\includegraphics` that has `frame` inserted at the end. Maybe you need `\newcommand{\embedimage}[1][]{\includegraphicsbak[#1]}`. If you're still having a problem, perhaps reduce your problem to a point where only the essentials are given...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the suggested answers, but this appears to be something very specific to generating TeX from Pandoc and embedding  Markdown images.

To solve the problem in my specific case, I have changed my Pandoc Markdown preamble to be:

```
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[intoc, title=]
    \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \newcommand*{\slide}[2][]{\includegraphics[frame,#1]{#2}}
    \let\embedimage\includegraphics
```

I realize that `\embedimage` is no longer necessary, but I already had references to it.  The second part of the fix as to do this in the doc:

```
\iffalse
![](./media/Slide2.png){ width=100% }
\fi
\slide{./media/Slide2.png}
```

This allows the Markdown preview in Visual Studio Code to function (the Markdown image tags work) but they are discarded from the LaTeX output, allowing me to use the custom `\slide` macro to display them.